# Why isn't the size of the array 7?

Tags: javascript

I am kind of confused why isnt the size of the array or object not being counted when the Smith is added to the list...?

```
var a = [];
a[0] = 12;
a[5] = "Lou";
a["Sue"] = "Smith";
console.log("a: ", a);
console.log("length: ", a.length);
```

Comment: It is 6 , 0 = 12, 1-4 = undefined, 5 = Lou. There is no elem in array with index "Sue"

Comment: Arrays contain items indexed with numeric properties.  When you use `["Sue"]` that just adds a regular property to the object that isn't counted as part of the array.

Comment: Hey why the downvote.. Its  a good question and should be appreciated..

Answer (score 3):

`Array.length` property just takes the last numerical *identifier* and adds one to it

(If the Array is formed by `Array` constructor, it will have that `length` assigned to it, which was passed to the constructor).

So, here the the last numerical identifier was `5` so length will return `5 + 1` which equals 6.

[**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Relationship_between_length_and_numerical_properties)

> When setting a property on a JavaScript array when the property is a
>   **valid array index** and that index is outside the current bounds of the
>   array, the engine will **update the array's length property accordingly**

Comment: Are you saying that the "last numerical identifier" of an empty array is `-1`? :-)

Comment: "*if it is empty it will be always be 0*". Not so. The length is always **at least** the largest index + 1. E.g. `var a = new Array(10);`. *a.length* is 10, but there are no members (the array is "empty").

Comment: @RobG no. The array isn't empty. It is `[undefinedx10]`, it has ten `undefined`

Comment: It's empty, there are no members, none. E.g. `a.hasOwnProperty('1')` returns false. Attempting to access `a[1]` returns undefined because that's what you get when attempting to access a non–existent property of any object.

Comment: @RobG arrayLength
If the only argument passed to the Array constructor is an integer between 0 and 232-1 (inclusive), this returns a new JavaScript array with length set to that number. If the argument is any other number, a RangeError exception is thrown.

Comment: Cool, so you can create an array with a huge length, that doesn't create any properties, it just sets the length.

Comment: @RobG that's from MDN. It's being set to 10, with `new Array(10)` call. How can I word my answer to make it better?

Comment: @RobG don't know if your comment is sarcastic but I took it from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array and I really hope you'd suggest me wordings to make my answer better

Comment: Nothing there contradicts what I've posted. You can set the array length to any number you like (within the limit you've noted). Doing that doesn't create any properties, it just sets the length. ;-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66636/discussion-between-amit-joki-and-robg).

Answer (score 3):

Because result array would looks like

```
[12, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, "Lou"]
```

I can say more, it would have a property `Sue`

```
a.Sue // -> "Smith"
Object.keys(a) // -> ["0", "5", "Sue"]
```

You can get more details with [this article](http://andrewdupont.net/2006/05/18/javascript-associative-arrays-considered-harmful/).

Comment: Yes thats what OP asks.. though `array` is still an `object` and it now contains a `properta.Sue` why isnt the length being calculated as 6

Comment: Note that there are no members at indexes 1 to 4, they don't exist. The equivalent array literal is `[12,,,,,"Lou"]`.